# How can I install Java on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

How can I install this version on ubuntu. I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: *1.25* ? What kind of version is that? Did you miss something there?

Comment: Mistake I mean 1.7.0.25. but I need 1.7.0.17

Comment: why would you want to install an outdated jdk?!?

Comment: because I had some problems with the current Grails version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with this syntax?

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk=7u17-2.3.8-1ubuntu1
```

Just be careful with the exact version, it should be compatible with your OS and you should do your research for your specific configuration before just copying and pasting the one I put. You could also get some other dependency errors which you would have to check...